# ASP.NET repeater how to get two divisions side by side

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootstrap-4

How is it possible to implement a repeater where content is diaplayed side by side

| name1 |
| --- |
| name2 |
| name3 |

This is what comes if I put one div content inside a repeater

After I  put two div in the repeater but I get the same thing in the same row

| name1 | name1 |
| --- | --- |
| name2 | name2 |
| name3 | name3 |

**Expected output is**:

| name1 | name2 |
| --- | --- |
| name3 | name4 |
| name5 | name6 |

I am not using a `grid view` instead of that I'm using `asp tags` and `bootstrap 4` cards

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                <!--One card-->
                <div class="card" style="width: 90%">
                    <div class="card-body"> 
 <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label>      
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
            
        </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Would you please share your code, so we can reproduce and possibly give you a solution?

Comment: why not create each item as a `<div>` the use CSS to match the layout with Flexbox? --> http://jsfiddle.net/balexandre/4zv6d02k/

Comment: updated code @Marco

Comment: i am using repeaters to get the things to be set i don't want to use a table to display the data the table in the question is just an interpretation of the page layout

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with pure css:

```
<style>
      * {
         box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      .row {
         display: flex;
         flex-direction: row;
         flex-wrap: wrap;
         width: 100%;
      }

      .column {
         border: 1px solid red;
         flex: 50%;
      }
   </style>
   <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rp2Columns">
      <HeaderTemplate>
         <div class="row">
      </HeaderTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
         <div class="column">
            <%# Eval("ProductId") %>
            <br />
            <%# Eval("ProductName") %>
            <br />
         </div>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <FooterTemplate>
         </div>
      </FooterTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
   public List<Product> Products = new List<Product>();
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
      {
         Products.Add(new Product { ProductId = i + 1, ProductName = $"Product - {i + 1}" });
      }

      this.rp2Columns.DataSource = Products;
      this.rp2Columns.DataBind();
   }
}

public class Product
{
   public int ProductId { get; set; }
   public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Now add bootstrap css decoration as needed.

Comment: you had a simple JsFiddle in the comments 

Comment: @balexandre guess I was already halfway-done with a quick webforms demo, when you posted the fiddle.